# Netbeans errors "No library found for namespace http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/dialogs"

Tags: jsf, maven, netbeans, pom.xml

I am having some error problems with my java code.

I have the following Code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
 xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
 xmlns:s="http://www.sensap.eu/jsf"
 xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
 xmlns:dialogs="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/dialogs"
 xmlns:widgets="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/widgets">
```

When I compile the code it is giving me the following error:

No library found for namespace http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/dialogs
No library found for namespace http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/widgets

I tried to check if the pom.xml is ok but from my end it looks fine. I don't know what to do next!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those `http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/*` namespaces don't refer to external libraries. So your Maven configuration is actually irrelevant. Those `http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/*` namespaces refer to the so-called [composite components](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info) which are actually XHTML files in the `/resources` folder of your own webapp which in turn use `<cc:interface><cc:implementation>` declarations.

Given the namespaces, you should have something like:

```
Web Pages
 |-- resources
 |    |-- components
 |    |    |-- dialogs
 |    |    |    |-- somedialog.xhtml
 |    |    |    `-- otherdialog.xhtml
 |    |    `-- widgets
 |    |         |-- somewidget.xhtml
 |    |         `-- otherwidget.xhtml
 :    :
```

If you actually have them and your webapp runs correctly with those composites, then it's just Netbeans itself who's not being smart enough to see them and giving a false error. Upgrading Netbeans and/or reporting the issue to Netbeans guys should solve it.

Comment: yes I have that structure :).. My netbeans version is 7.4 and when I checked for updates, it is saying that my IDE is up to date! Will report it to Netbeans Guys. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

This is, in my opinion, a Maven/Netbeans intetgration problem. Netbeans should infer the neccesary Frameworks from your maven dependencies. Frameworks is a propietary Netbeans mechanism, that affects how your opened files will be processed. Open your project properties in netbeans, there is an option called "Frameworks". In your case, i guess, the list may be empty. Try to add the JavaServer faces framework as shown in attached picture.[image]

In case you find some problem adding the framework read this link [Netbeans framework issue](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=229366)

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget to also migrate the namespace in your composite components:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite">
  <cc:interface>
  </cc:interface> 
  ...
```